# PUT and DELETE in RESTful WCF Service cause 401 Unauthorized error

Tags: wcf, rest, http-status-code-401

I have a RESTful web service in IIS 7.5 that is working just fine in our Development environment.  Now we have deployed to a QA environment and we are getting 401 errors only on the PUT and DELETE verbs.  I have read a lot about 405 errors, but not much about 401 errors.  Here is the exact error message whenever I attempt a PUT or a DELETE.

> `The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Anonymous'. The authentication header received from the server was ''`

Does anyone have any ideas?

Corey

Comment: have you compared you app pool configuration and web.configs between the two environments? do they have any notable differences?

Comment: Yes, the app pool configurations and the web.configs are exactly the same in both environments.  (the only difference in web.configs is the connection string to the database)

Comment: possibly a permission problem (http://goneale.com/2009/10/22/wcf-the-http-request-is-unauthorized-with-client-authentication-scheme-anonymous/). Are the folder permissions between dev and QA exaclty the same?

Comment: That was it!  You are a genius Zach Green!  Thanks so much.  It's funny, I looked at the link you sent and it looked familiar from when I configured the DEV environment.  I did a bad job of configuration management since I forgot that I had made that same change in DEV.  Thanks again.  If you go ahead and answer the question then I can mark it as the correct answer and you can get credit.

Comment: Execellent. Glad you got it fixed.