# 401 Unauthorized with OData Update and Delete

Tags: azure, odata, wcf-data-services, restlet, http-status-code-401

For the first time I have stumbled upon a problem where the solution has not already been provided (completely) on SO, but I hope someone out there can help.

My problem is similar to [PUT and DELETE in RESTful WCF Service cause 401 Unauthorized error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6062471/put-and-delete-in-restful-wcf-service-cause-401-unauthorized-error) .

That is, I have a WCF Data Service where I get a 401 whenever I try to do updates or deletes (read and post works without any problems). The difference to the abovementioned post is that I am not hosting my service in IIS but on Windows Azure, so I am not able to apply that solution.

I have the same problem (`401: invalid credentials when attempting updates or deletes`) on both a .NET client and a restlet client using the OData extension. However, on the .NET client I am able to resolve the issue by setting UsePostTunneling = true.

In my service I have set `config.SetEntitySetAccessRule("*", EntitySetRights.All)`.

Does anyone know how I can resolve the issue for my restlet client?

Answer (score 0):

First thing I would check is to see if you have PUT and DELETE verbs enabled in your handlers.  Are you running this from a web role in full IIS or are you using Hosted Web Core (HWC), or something else?  Usually, more than a 401, I see a 405 error because WebDAV is on the machine and PUT and DELETE verbs conflict there.  You end up having to disable WebDAV for the app.

I would also check your authentication method in your web.config.  I have seen the 'none' type cause issues, so change that to Forms.

Comment: Thanks dunnry, but I am hosting my service on Windows Azure (using an SQL Azure database) - not IIS. So I am guessing that the IIS settings does not apply (I'm completely new to this so I am guessing). To be able to update/delete on my restlet client, I figure that I will either have to resolve the issue in my service or in my client (as mentioned, for my .NET client I could get it to work by using post tunneling). FYI: For developing my service I followed the tutorial at http://msdn.microsoft.com/da-dk/data/gg192994.

Comment: Windows Azure is Windows...running IIS.  So, it most definitely applies.  However, if you are not using a webrole, the answer might change slightly.  *Edit*, I see from the tutorial that you are using Webrole with full IIS.  Please check the solutions I mentioned (look at handlers, try removing WebDAV module, and check authentication method in web.config)