# Azure REST PUT or DELETE  returns 401

Tags: wcf, azure, http-status-code-401

I've just uploaded my WCF REST based service to Azure.

When I try to use PUT or DELETE I get a 401, Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials.

It runs fine in my local and Azure development environments

I've seen other posts referencing Certificates and Permissions.

[401 Unauthorized with OData Update and Delete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6705514/401-unauthorized-with-odata-update-and-delete) (PUT and DELETE verbs are enabled in IIS, by default)

http://goneale.com/2009/10/22/wcf-the-http-request-is-unauthorized-with-client-authentication-scheme-anonymous/ (doesn't apply because of Azure)

I'm running default settings

Comment: Can you provide any more detail about what the WCF service is using the verbs to do?  There is a chance the 403 has nothing to do with Azure, but more with permissions, etc on the server itself .. knowing that say "A PUT causes a file to be created, or a db entry to change" could provide better answers

Comment: I created a Ping Service, where all it does is returns the parameter or body sent. 
I still get the error for PUT and DELETE where Post and Get are fine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had to add

```
<authentication mode="None" />
```

to my web.config

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsazuretroubleshooting/thread/514f2e2d-54a8-4516-976d-94a879209173

Comment: It fixed my problem but it seems that adding "authentication" is rendering debugging impossible (the breakpoints are not loaded).