# WCF REST Service - 401 Unauthorized

Tags: wcf, iis, rest, iis-7, http-status-code-401

We're in the process of developing a WCF REST web service which just receives a bunch of arbitrary text from any anonymous user and then performs some processing on the back end.

For example, here's one method from our web service:

```
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Required)]
public class MyRESTService : IMyRESTService
{
    [WebInvoke(Method = "PUT", UriTemplate = "/MyRESTMethod?paramA={paramA}&paramB={paramB}")]
    public Stream MyRESTMethod(string paramA, string paramB, Stream rawData)
    {
        //do some stuff...
    }
}
```

If we just use the default IIS settings we get a `(401) Unauthorized`. However, after much trial and error we figured out that we could get it to work by giving WRITE access to 'Everyone' on the actual `.svc` file for our service.

My question is: why in the world would IIS need to have WRITE access to an `.svc` file for this to work? Is there a better way or am I stuck with this hackish (and possibly insecure) workaround?

WTF Microsoft?

Possibly related:

- [PUT and DELETE in RESTful WCF Service cause 401 Unauthorized error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6062471/put-and-delete-in-restful-wcf-service-cause-401-unauthorized-error)
- [IIS7 Post/Put/Patch/Delete WCF oData - Authentication Failure 401.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21611291/iis7-post-put-patch-delete-wcf-odata-authentication-failure-401-3)

Comment: The access rights do not necessarily need to be granted to "Everyone". Instead the authenticated user must have these rights. For anonymous access this is IUSR.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After talking to a tech representative from M$ I was informed that this is indeed the expected behavior. The service must have write access enabled for someone to send a request to it, and when you do this it will actually set write access automatically on the .SVC file as well.

Comment: You saved my day! BTW: Thinking about it a second time this does kind of make sense: When you request a PUT on a resource, that resource must allow write access. Now, I guess REST with WCF is probably implemented such that IIS interprets a PUT /foobar.svc/some/path as a PUT request on /foobar.svc and forwards the "/some/path" part to WCF for further interpretation. So, for IIS this is a PUT request on /foobar.svc - in HTTP speaking: You want to modify foobar.svc

Answer (score 10):

I have also found this can be fixed by putting

`<authentication mode="None" />` inside of `<system.web>` in your `web.config`

Comment: this helped me as well, but is it safe?

Comment: Depends on your environment. In my case, we were trusting the network was secure, and maybe that is sufficient. If you need direct authentication between services, obviously this will be a problem.