# IIS7 Post/Put/Patch/Delete WCF oData - Authentication Failure 401.3

Tags: wcf, iis, model-view-controller, odata

After migrating from IIS6 to IIS7, all sites using a WCF oData service would prompt for credentials when attempting to make Post/Put/Patch/Delete request. The user would be continually prompted for credentials until the cancelled the request. After cancelling the request, they would receive a `401.3` response from the server.

If a user is granted modify permission on the folder containing the `*.svc` file for the WCF oData service they are then authorized to make requests with those verbs. Asp.Net impersonation is **not** turned on.

The AppPool is running Integrated .Net 4 under a service account with modify permissions to the site's folders/files.

**Update:** 
It seems this is as designed. Granting`ServerName\Users` modify access to the `*.svc`, does resolve the issue. *Addendum: Specifically, it looks like `Domain Users` or `Authenticated Users` needs modify rights to the `*.svc`.*

*Final update: changed the wording to make the question more general/easy to find for others*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is by design. If you disable impersonation, then NTFS ACLs are used to secure the resource. I know it seems odd at first, but some thought will lead you to an understanding that it is a reasonable approach given the constraints of this particular configuration. This behaviour is documented on MSDN.

Comment: I've gone ahead and accepted this. For completeness though, can you provide the MSDN document you referred to?